# Field from meta boxes doesn't display values in Quick Edit mode

Tags: wordpress

I've created custom meta box. Now I'm trying to add this meta box to Quick Edit option. Unfortunately, no values from meta box field is displaying in Quick Edit mode, in this same field. Of course in page edit values are assigned correctly. What could be wrong?

```
// Adding a metabox
function add_custom_metabox() {
    $post_types = get_post_types(); // Get all post types
    unset($post_types['revision']); // Exclude the 'revision' post type
    unset($post_types['acf-field-group']); // Exclude the 'acf-field-group' post type
    unset($post_types['loos-cbp']); // Exclude the 'loos-cbp' post type

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        add_meta_box(
            'header-h1',
            'Header H1',
            'render_custom_metabox',
            $post_type,
            'side',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_metabox');

// Rendering the metabox content
function render_custom_metabox($post) {
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header-h1-field', true);
    ?>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
        <label for="header-h1-input">ENTER HEADER:</label>
        <input type="text" id="header-h1-input" name="header-h1-input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>">
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Saving the metabox field value
function save_custom_metabox($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['header-h1-input'])) {
        $value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['header-h1-input']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'header-h1-field', $value);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_metabox');

// Adding a column in the admin view
function add_custom_column_header_h1($columns) {
    $columns['header_h1'] = 'Header H1';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_custom_column_header_h1');
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'add_custom_column_header_h1');

// Displaying the column content in the admin view
function display_custom_column_header_h1($column_name, $post_id) {
    if ($column_name === 'header_h1') {
        $value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'header-h1-field', true);
        echo esc_html($value);
    }
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'display_custom_column_header_h1', 10, 2);
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'display_custom_column_header_h1', 10, 2);

// Adding metabox fields to Quick Edit
function add_custom_quick_edit_fields() {
    $post_types = get_post_types(); // Get all post types
    unset($post_types['revision']); // Exclude the 'revision' post type
    unset($post_types['acf-field-group']); // Exclude the 'acf-field-group' post type
    unset($post_types['loos-cbp']); // Exclude the 'loos-cbp' post type

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        add_action("quick_edit_custom_box", "render_custom_quick_edit_fields", 10, 2);
        add_action("save_post_" . $post_type, "save_custom_quick_edit_fields", 10, 2);
    }
}
add_action("admin_init", "add_custom_quick_edit_fields");

// Rendering metabox fields in Quick Edit
function render_custom_quick_edit_fields($column_name, $post_type) {
    if ($column_name !== "header_h1") {
        return;
    }

    // Retrieving the metabox field value from data attributes
    $value = "";
    if (isset($_GET["post"])) {
        $post_id = intval($_GET["post"]);
        $value = get_post_meta($post_id, "header-h1-field", true);
    }
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
        <div class="inline-edit-col">
            <span class="title">Header H1</span>
            <input type="text" name="header_h1" class="header-h1-input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>" data-default-value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}

// Saving metabox field values from Quick Edit
function save_custom_quick_edit_fields($post_id) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST["header_h1"])) {
        $value = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST["header_h1"]);
        update_post_meta($post_id, "header-h1-field", $value);
    }
}
```

The point is: meta box in page edit with field, and the same field in Quick Edit.